# Is 1/8" plywood enough to prevent racking or do I need 1/4"?

Tags: plywood, racking

I'm making a shelving unit from 3/4" plywood. The unit will be 6 feet high by 3 feet wide and I'm concerned about racking. I could use corner brackets on the back, but I was thinking it might look nicer if I backed the whole unit with plywood, providing a back and also the needed stability.

My question is: would 1/8" plywood provide enough stability, or do I really need 1/4"?

Comment: Yes, to echo what @jdv says 1/8" is more than sufficient for this normally. As long as the sheet of whatever it is *is* held securely, by any fasteners or glue (glueing is most definitely an option with plywood and other manmade board materials that are dimensionally stable) it'll do what's needed to prevent racking. Are you planning on just tacking it on the back, or housing it in a groove or rebate? There's an argument in favour of housing the backer board as the superior option, but honestly if you use dots of glue and/or plenty of fasteners there's probably no real difference.

Comment: I think it'll look nicer housed in a rebate, if that's just as secure. Also, the sides and top and bottom are all 3/4" plywood. Can you rout such a rebate in that?

Comment: Yeah you can route a rebate like that no problem. How good the result is mostly comes down to the quality of your ply though! If your ply is reasonable quality or better this should work very nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at how backs are used to stiffen flat-pack furniture. It's often nominally 1/8th in. (usually) paperboard, as it only has to hold the fasteners to the back and resist those fasteners wallowing out.

Of course, enough racking force over time can work fasteners out, or wallow out the holes.

You'll notice that flat-pack construction also often has the backing drop into a rabbeted groove around the back. This provides an easy way to square things up as long as you know the backing is square, and it provides an edge for the backing to resist racking beyond the fasteners.

But 1/8 in. *plywood* will be sufficient in most cases. The assumption is that you would use panel nails or similar fasteners to help keep them from working themselves out.

Comment: I thought the point of the backing was to provide rigidity so that the 90 degree angle between sides and top/bottom can't rack, and maybe also if you want a back surface. In this application, I don't need the backing layer for functionality (although it might be nice), but I was thinking it would work to prevent racking. Is that the case?

Comment: Also, if I didn't want the back to be visible from the side, I'd want to rout out a rabbet in which to place the plywood. Can you do this if the sides are also plywood, and would that compromise the anti-racking function of the backing?

Comment: Yes, it is to make it more rigid, if the construction material or method of construction does not offer a lot of natural rigidity. This is what I meant when I used the word "stiffen", above. It acts as bracing. Sometimes you can get away with a strip of material at the top, joining the top corners together, and maybe a rectangle halfway down and again at the bottom (depending on your construction).

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about preventing racking is that it can be done completely through tension.  Almost any normal construction material is quite strong in tension.  1/8" plywood should be fine, as would be hardboard, paperboard, etc.  You don't even need the whole back, going from corner-to-corner diagonally in both directions is sufficient.  Steel cables or even stout cord will work fine.

Comment: Good to mention wire and turnbuckles (or just twist them to simulate turnbuckles).